# Foreach not working - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need to print the below array structure as:

```
Node Title 1

  topic 1

  topic 2

  topic 3

  topic 4

    asset title1 

    asset title2

    asset title3
```

How can i do using foreach - PHP

**What i have done is :**

```
foreach($output['fields'] as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 'title') {
            echo $value;
        }
        if(count($value['main_topic'])) {
            foreach($value['main_topic'] AS $mainkey => $main_topic) {
                echo $main_topic['topic_title'];
            }
        }
    }
```

**The above syntax is printing the title. But not the main_topic array.**

```
Array
(
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [nid] => 136
            [node_title] => Node title 1
            [node_type] => curriculum
            [title] => Node title 1
            [main_topic] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [row_id] => 136
                            [topic_id] => 411847
                            [weight] => 10
                            [topic_title] => topic 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [row_id] => 136
                            [topic_id] => 411839
                            [weight] => 2
                            [topic_title] => topic 2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [row_id] => 136
                            [topic_id] => 411840
                            [weight] => 3
                            [topic_title] => topic 3
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [row_id] => 136
                            [topic_id] => 411841
                            [weight] => 4
                            [topic_title] => topic 4
                            [subfield] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [asset_title] => asset title 1
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [asset_title] => asset title 2
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [asset_title] => asset title 3
                                        )

                                )

                        )


                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are iterating over all `$output['fields']`. 
There will never be a `$value` with key `'main_topic'` because the key `'main_topic'` is contained in the `$output['fields']` array and thus exists only as `$key` in your foreach. The array you want is `$value`

Your code should be like:

```
foreach($output['fields'] as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 'title') {
            echo $value;
            continue;
        }
        if($key == 'main_topic' && is_array($value)) {
            foreach($value as $main_topic) {
                echo $main_topic['topic_title'];
            }
        }
    }
```

---

To complete this answer with a full solution (including asset titles), below is how I would write it.

Because `$output['fields']` is the starting point and to make the code more readable, I create a reference to the starting node using the `=&` operator so the array is not copied in memory. I do the same with the inner `foreach`s. Since we are not modifying data, referencing the variables is sufficient and consumes less memory and CPU:

```
if (is_array($output['fields'])) {
    $node =& $output['fields'];
    echo $node['title'];
    if(is_array($node['main_topic'])) {
        foreach($node['main_topic'] as &$main) {
            echo $main['topic_title'];
            if(is_array($main['subfield'])) {
                foreach($main['subfield'] as &$asset) {
                    echo $asset['asset_title'];
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
else {
    echo "no menu";
}
```

Comment: yes i just realized myself that i stopped fixing the code right after the first mistake. i corrected the inner-foreach too in my edit.

Comment: Post has been edited to give a more elaborative explanation on `$node =& $output['node'];`

Answer (score 1):

`$value` is the array, not `$key['main_topic']`

```
foreach($output['fields'] as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'title') {
        echo $value;
    }
    if($key == 'main_topic') {
        foreach($value as $mainkey => $main_topic) {
            echo $main_topic['topic_title'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need the additional key:

```
echo $value['main_topic'][$mainkey]['topic_title'];
```

Comment: $main_topic is the iterated object. No need to specify a key.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting your array sections confused.

Try (and I haven't tested this) :

```
echo $output['node_title']."\n";
foreach ($output['fields'] as $key=>$value)
{
    switch ($key)
    {
        case 'title':
            echo $value."\n";
            break;
        case 'main_topic':
            if (count($value) > 0)
            {
                foreach ($value as $main_block)
                {
                    echo "\t".$main_block['topic_title']."\n";
                    if (array_key_exists('subfield',$main_block)!==FALSE)
                    {
                        foreach ($main_block['subfield'] as $subfield_block)
                        {
                            echo "\t\t".$subfield_block['asset_title']."\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```